# Linq-to-Sql: recursively get children

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, common-table-expression

I have a Comment table which has a CommentID and a ParentCommentID. I am trying to get a list of all children of the Comment. This is what I have so far, I haven't tested it yet.

```
private List<int> searchedCommentIDs = new List<int>();
// searchedCommentIDs is a list of already yielded comments stored
// so that malformed data does not result in an infinite loop.
public IEnumerable<Comment> GetReplies(int commentID) {
    var db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var replies = db.Comments
        .Where(c => c.ParentCommentID == commentID 
            && !searchedCommentIDs.Contains(commentID));
    foreach (Comment reply in replies) {
        searchedCommentIDs.Add(CommentID);
        yield return reply;
        // yield return GetReplies(reply.CommentID)); // type mis-match.
        foreach (Comment replyReply in GetReplies(reply.CommentID)) {
            yield return replyReply;
        }
    }
}
```

2 questions:

1. Is there any obvious way to improve this? (Besides maybe creating a view in sql with a CTE.)
2. How come I can't yield a `IEnumerable <Comment>` to an IEnumerable `<Comment>`, only `Comment` itself?
3. Is there anyway to use SelectMany in this situation?

Comment: Is this Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably use either a UDF/CTE, or (for very deep structures) a stored procedure that does the same manually.

Note that if you can change the schema, you can pre-index such recursive structures into an indexed/ranged tree that lets you do a single BETWEEN query - but the maintenance of the tree is expensive (i.e. query becomes cheap, but insert/update/delete become expensive, or you need a delayed scheduled task).

---

Re 2 - you can only `yield` the type specified in the enumeration (the `T` in `IEnumerable<T>` / `IEnumerator<T>`).

You could `yield` an `IEnumerable<Comment>` **if** the method returned `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Comment>>` - does that make sense?

Improvements:

- perhaps a *udf* (to keep composability, rather than a stored procedure) that uses the CTE recursion approach
- use `using`, since `DataContext` is `IDisposable`...

so:

```
using(var db = new MyDataContext() ) { /* existing code */ }
```

- [LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534268.aspx) is worth a try, but I'm not sure I'd be hopeful...
- the list of searched ids is risky as a field - I guess you're OK as long as you don't call it twice... personally, I'd use an argument on a private backing method... (i.e. pass the list between recursive calls, but not on the public API)

Comment: yea it makes perfect sense im just not sure why they wouldnt let you either return an ienumerable of a type or the type tiself

Comment: You can **return** an IEnumerable<T> of the type. You can **yield return** a T.

Comment: right i completley understand but i think you should be able to do either

Comment: If it was only the generic (typed) versions in existence, I expect it could... the problem is that it would be very ambiguous for the non-generic versions... you can `yield` any object, so it wouldn't know whether that represented 1 item or a sequence. Personally, I'm happy the simple way it is now.