# Fill a Recursive Data Structure from a Self-Referential Database Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

This question refers to http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2009/02/08/asp.net-mvc-recursive-treeview-helper.aspx

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [matthidinger.com](http://blog2.matthidinger.com/ContentImages/ASP.NETMVCRecursiveTreeViewHelper_B445/image_3.png))</sub>

And I have a recursive data structure that looks like this:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode(){}
    public string NodeId { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TreeNode> Children { get; }
}
```

How do I fill this recursive data structure from the table using Linq?

**NOTE:** For purposes of this question, please assume that I already have a perfectly efficient table; i.e. it is completely resident in memory, or it is being access using a CTE.  Really, I am just looking for the Linq queries to get it from the Linq to SQL DataContext to the recursive object.  I am aware it will probably involve a ForEach and a recursive function call; I just can't quite get my head around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535436/linq-to-sql-recursively-get-children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is to query the hierachy in SQL using CTEs. LINQ2SQL and hierachical/relational data don't mix too nicely. See [Hierarchical data in Linq - options and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202912/hierarchical-data-in-linq-options-and-performance/203071#203071).

Comment: I see from the MSDN examples that this produces a list in the correct hierarchical order.  Does that allow me to walk the list linearly to build my recursive structure, and is that why the performance is better?

Comment: The CTE queries are the only way to produce the result set for 'I need all the childrens of current node, and the children of the children and so on' in SQL. Is not an issue of order (that is just a side effect of execution), but correctness. If you can afford to fetch the *entire* table in the client, then there is no need to use  CTE, one can use just a an ordinary query then build the in memory tree. Also if you only need the children of a current node (eg. to instantiate the Childrens iterator) then again there is no need of CTEs, an ordinary `SELECT ... WHERE Parent=@id` will do.