# Get unknown amount of parents using LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, parent-child

Given the following:

```
public class Person
{
  public int  PersonId { get; set; }
  public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I have the following tree structure (PersonID - ParentID):

```
1 - null
  2 - 1
    3 - 2
  4 - 1
```

How can I get all the parents of PersonId `3`, or `2,1` using a LINQ to SQL query?

*Note:  A `null` ParentId denotes a top-level Person*

Comment: Sounds like recursion; you'd do that kind of thing with a CTE in Sql land, but I think that is too complex for Linq2Sql. Might want to make a proc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hierarchy Problem -> Replace Recursion with Linq Join??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435229/hierarchy-problem-replace-recursion-with-linq-join)

Comment: @Chris: That's a different kind of problem.  That searches for descendants of a hierarchy while this one searches for the ancestors.

Comment: @Jeff - but the reason LINQ won't work is the same for both problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535436/linq-to-sql-recursively-get-children & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976325/fill-a-recursive-data-structure-from-a-self-referential-database-table & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202912/hierarchical-data-in-linq-options-and-performance

Comment: You are trying to create a hierarchical query. The first four results should help you further: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=hierarchical%20query%20linq

Comment: I think a reqursive CTE in SQL is the best way to go. Linq can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a loop (or other form of recursion).

```
var personId = 3 as int?;
var result = new List<Person>();
do
{
    var person = context.Persons.Single(p => p.PersonId == personId.Value);
    result.Add(person);
    personId = person.ParentId;
} while (personId != null);
// all ancestors are in `result`
```

Comment: Would you know how to do it, the other way around?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859520/get-unknown-amount-of-childen-using-linq-to-sql

Comment: @Brian: The concept is the same.  Instead of taking the starting person and going to the parent, you need to go to the child.  In this case, you need to find the people who's parent is the target person.  Then for each of these people, repeat.