# Recursive self join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have table as below. I need to get all the manager id's for the user id provided.

```
userid managerid
10     1
9      10
6      9
2      6
4      1
```

If i pass 2 to my method I need to get 1,10,9 and 6. I have written the below query which will return only first level parent. I.e it will return only 6 & 9.

```
public List<int?> mymethod (int userId){

return (from e in mycontext.EmployeeManagers
                     join e1 in m_context.EmployeeManagers
                        on e.UserId equals e1.ManagerId
                    where e1.UserId == userId
                     select e1.ManagerId).AsQueryable().ToList()
}
```

How can I modify the query to return all the manager hirerachy?

please help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072166/linq-to-sql-recursive-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply run a short loop like this (sorry for invalid capitalization, coded from scratch):

```
public List<Int> GetAllManagers(int userID)
{
  var result = new List<int>();
  int index = 0;
  result.add(userID); // start with user (it will be removed later)
  while (index < result.count)
  {
    var moreData = from e in mycontext.EmployeeManagers
                    where e.UserId == result[index];
                     select e.ManagerId;
    foreach (int id in moreData)
      if (result.indexOf(id)==-1)
        result.add(id);
    index++;
  }
  result.delete(0);
  return result;
}
```

or recursevly

```
private void AddUniqueIds (List<int> elements, ref List<int> list)
{
  foreach (int id in elements)
    if (list.indexOf(id)==-1)
      list.add(id);
}
public List<int> GetAllManagers(int userID)
{
  var result = new List<int>();
  var moreData = from e in mycontext.EmployeeManagers
                 where e.UserId == result[index];
                 select e.ManagerId;

  foreach (int id in moreData)
    AddUniqueIds(result, GetAllManagers(id));

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this in a sinqle LINQ expression. You have to run this in a loop.

A better option is to do this in the database and then return the results to LINQ.

See:

- [Hierarchical data in Linq - options and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202912/hierarchical-data-in-linq-options-and-performance)
- [Fill a Recursive Data Structure from a Self-Referential Database Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976325/fill-a-recursive-data-structure-from-a-self-referential-database-table)
- [Linq-to-Sql: recursively get children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535436/linq-to-sql-recursively-get-children)

Comment: There is no recursive join in LINQ simply because only few database engines support it. Consider [this elegant solution for hierarchical data handling in database](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different pattern.

Lets see that you get your query.

```
var query = myContext.EmployeeManagers
```

Then, you could `join` it however you want to

```
for(int = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    query = query.Join( ... ..., i, ... ); // Can't recall all
                                           // the parameters right now.
}
```

And then just execute it:

```
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Note it would require you to know max depth level, which is not always the case.

Comment: -1 Where does this magic 5 come from? How do you expect to return a list, from doing multiple joins? I'd expect this to return j1.managerid, j2.managerid, j3.managerid, ... in a single result.

Comment: @Gregory not knowing the max depth will result an stackoverflow exception.

Comment: @Jacco it was the example of looped multiple joins.